# Why does dividing an integer by a float produce off-precision results?

Tags: c, floating-point, division

I'm trying to divide an integer by a float using this simple code:

```
float result = 0;
int randomInt = [random integer between 100 and 500];
result = 323 / 10.00;

printf("result is: %f\n",result);
```

The output of printf is sometimes off by 0.00001 or so:

```
32.999998  //323/10.00
45.000001  //450/10.00
29.099998  //290/10.00
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Since the `float` representation used by most implementations is good for only 6-7 decimal digits of precision, you should consider using a `printf` format that avoids emitting more.  For your particular case, maybe `%.4f` to get results rounded to four digits after the decimal point (as your particular outputs will always have exactly two digits before the decimal point, for six digits total).

Comment: Aside: "divide an integer by a float" --> `323 / 10.00` is an `int` divided by a `double`.

Comment: "Why does this happen?" --> `float` can represent about2^32 different values.  3.23 is _not_ one of them.  A value near `32.999998` is the closet `float.`

Comment: Consider `7/3` also forms an "off-precision result" of 2 and not 2.333333....  Some operations with a computer differ than _math_.

Comment: Hi also dividing integers in C and assigning the result to a double is the perfect example of why you need to cast your integer to float first before trying the operation

Comment: @Yunnosch, yeah I agree.

Comment: I doubt the example outputs are valid (at least not matching the comment behind). `450/10.0` and `290/10.0` have exact results and `323/10.0` should be something like `32.299...` or `32.30...1`